# SD0_NNcannot be evaluated without using index

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-spatial

I know this is a frequently discussed error but I am not able to get my hands through it even after trying really hard.

I have the following query that works fine

```
SELECT b.BID
FROM STUDENT s,
     BUILDINGS b
WHERE sdo_nn(b.LOC, s.LOC, 'sdo_num_res=1', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

and shows the nearest neighbor of each s. But what I want is to display the BID of the top 2 **b** that appears the most, so I change my query to this:

```
SELECT b.BID, count(b.BID)
FROM STUDENT s,
     BUILDINGS b
WHERE sdo_nn(b.LOC, s.LOC, 'sdo_num_res=1', 1) = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY b.BID
```

and then it fails with the error **SDO_NN cannot be evaluated without using index**.

Can you please help with this problem or tell me an alternate way to do it.

Comment: Why do you have both `mysql` and `oracle` tags? Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: My mistake, I am using ORACLE

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a subquery:

```
SELECT BID, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT b.BID
      FROM STUDENT s,
           BUILDINGS b
      WHERE sdo_nn(b.LOC, s.LOC, 'sdo_num_res=1', 1) = 'TRUE'
     ) b
GROUP BY BID;
```

I'm not sure why the subquery is needed, but if the first query works, this one should as well.

Note:  I'd be inclined to write this using an explicit `join` (because I abhor commas in the `from` clause):

```
SELECT BID, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT b.BID
      FROM STUDENT s JOIN
           BUILDINGS b
           ON sdo_nn(b.LOC, s.LOC, 'sdo_num_res=1', 1) = 'TRUE'
     ) b
GROUP BY BID;
```

Comment: Still gives the exact same error. I have also added both LOC in the metadata

Comment: Is there another way of finding the top two B using sdo_nn command that are the nearest number of most S?